# Change one DataObject field's value before insert using ObjectDataSouce

Tags: asp.net, webforms, radgrid

I have RadGrid bind with ObjectDataSource and the ObjectDataSource is using my repository for CRUD operations, the issues are:

1. I want to change the format of the dates before insert them.
2. I want to set one field value "I'll get it from QueryString"

I tried ItemCreating and ItemCreated events but this is not working. Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you can use Inserting ObjectDataSource Event to get the object that will be inserted like the following:

```
protected void obsShiftPeriods_Inserting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
    var newShitPeriod = e.InputParameters[0] as DataModel.ShiftPeriod;
    if (newShitPeriod != null) 
     newShitPeriod.ShiftId = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["ShiftId"]);
}
```

e.InputParameters[0] is the object will be inserted, after getting the object you can assign any field, and boom you're done ObjectDataSource will do the remaining for you.